# Same function showing different results

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I was trying to encrypt data with help of following function in a desktop application :

```
public String[] binaryToText(String[] binary1,int lengthofshares)
{
    String[] encrptedfinally=new String[lengthofshares];
    for(int tt=0;tt<lengthofshares;tt++){
        String ss2="";
        String ss=binary1[tt];
        char mynextChar;

        for(int i = 0; i < ss.length(); i += 8) //this is a little tricky.  we want [0, 7], [9, 16], etc
        {
            System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(ss.substring(i, i+8), 2)+",");
            mynextChar = (char)Integer.parseInt(ss.substring(i, i+8), 2);
            System.out.println(mynextChar);
            ss2 += mynextChar;

        }
        encrptedfinally[tt]=ss2;

    }
return encrptedfinally;

}
```

But when i used the same function in a web application it gives different results.The integer.parseInt statement returns the same value but the character in which it is typecasted gets changed.

In web application some positions are replaced by question marks '?'

Web application pic in which each row correspond to integer and then character it being typecasted to : http://postimg.org/image/ydn9h9nsf/

and in desktop application the values are :

http://postimg.org/image/ww88p3ot5/

What can be the reason ?Please help.

Comment: If you want [0, 7], [9, 16] why are you only adding 8 on each iteration rather than 9?

Comment: @JonSkeet as for [i,j] their is j-i+1 values.and my logic is correct as it run fine on my desktop application.

Comment: Also it would be *much* clearer if you would just include the sample data in your post (as text) rather than as images hosted elsewhere. What is `binary1` here? If it's binary data, it shouldn't be stored in a string to start with. It's very unclear what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment at all... partly because it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JonSkeet i posted image because when i tried to copy that symbol from output screen it doesnt get copied.Also it is just a string of 0 and 1.I again wanna say that logic dont have any problem.

Comment: That's very odd - you should be able to copy it into a web form reasonably. Anyway, you still haven't explained what the input is or the expected output. Using `char` to store arbitrary binary data is a *really, really* bad idea. (And this doesn't sound like encryption at all...)

Comment: @JonSkeet if u wanna see the code i pasted it here http://pastebin.com/JCFEctDF .Though it is big but may reduce the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet Copy not from web ,I printed it on console itself.But was nt able to copy that symbol from their

Comment: Apparently that has been removed - but even so, I don't think it would explain *what you're trying to achieve*. You should be able to do that in the question itself, just with words. What is your input? What is your expected output and why?

Comment: Actually its a project so i cant explain whole code here.Thats why tried to post only relevent work

Comment: I give up at this point, I'm afraid. I didn't ask you to explain the whole code - I asked you to explain what this method was trying to achieve. If you can't even explain that, then we can't help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet hey,I give you complete code that am using .Now provided the encryption key,a integer length and a byte arraylist one can easily get whats the probelm i guess

Comment: There are *so* many problems with this that it's hard to know where to start. Your idea of encryption is a long way from my idea of encryption, too. You should use standard crypto algorithms, designed and implemented by people who are experts in cryptography. Then you shouldn't try to use text to store arbitrary binary data. If you *do* have to use text for that, base64-encode the `byte[]` to get ASCII text.

Comment: @JonSkeet how to use base64 ?

Comment: Search for it - there are *hundreds* of answers using base64 in Java on Stack Overflow, and loads of other examples on the web. But I'd strongly suggest starting from scratch on this, rather than trying to plug base64 into the code you've got.

Comment: @JonSkeet i just want to replace these '?' in web app with their original characters.Thats it.My remaining code is fine

Comment: No, your whole approach is fundamentally flawed. I don't think I'm going to be able to convince you of that, so I'm going to stop participating in this question.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is most likely that the desktop and web applications are using different character encodings.

That is why under some encodings the value would present one character, and in others a different one.

Comment: How to get the same results then?As in my desktop application

Comment: How to convert the character encoding of my web application to get the same results ?

Comment: The "value" (as a `char`) always represents the same character. Whether that character is correctly encoded in the web application is a different matter - we don't really have enough context here to say. I believe the approach is fundamentally broken anyway though.